# A data de uma venda muda quando o registro da venda é atualizado

Tags: mysql, sql

A coluna `data_venda TIMESTAMP(0)` da minha tabela `venda` retorna a hora atual da venda em meu formulário de cadastro de venda.

Só que em um formulário de atualização onde atualizo a venda o horário muda, e eu não queria esse tipo de coisa, pois se uma venda foi feita semana passada ela deveria ficar com o horário da venda na semana passada. Como eu corrigo isso?

Comment: só não atualizar esse campo na tabela quando atualizar a venda, ou ter certeza de passar o mesmo valor que já existe

Comment: Não coloquei esse campo para atualizar, mas atualiza do mesmo jeito.

Comment: bom sem ver o código fica difícil, mas a solução básica é, ou não atualiza ou pega o valor atual antes de atualizar

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Evita que o mysql altere o campo `data_venda` quando houver um `UPDATE`

```
CREATE TABLE venda (
   data_venda TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score -2):

Já tentou trocar a atribuição do campo de TIMESTAMP na hora da criação da tabela? Poderia testar colocando o **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** ou o **DEFAULT NOW()**

Segue um exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_VENDA (
data_venda1 DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
data_venda1 DEFAULT NOW()
)
```

Comment: Apenas sinalizando, que essa alteração poderá ser útil caso seja possível realizar essa alteração na propria tabela. Espero ter ajudado Dev Snake